# Confusion of nested ifelse expression

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider below expression:

```
x$Y = ifelse(x$A<= 5 & abs(x$B) >= 2, 
            ifelse(x$B> 2 ,"YES","NO"),
            'NA')
```

What I understand is that, if A is <=5 and B >=2 then ALL are YES, if not then NO, but I am confused the second `ifelse` condition. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code aims to define a new column, `Y` in the data set `x`. The column `Y` will populate based on the following statements:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we rewrite your `ifelse` expression using expanded syntax, it might be easier to understand.

```r
x$Y <- ifelse(x$A <= 5 & abs(x$B) >= 2, ifelse(x$B > 2, "YES", "NO"), 'NA')

# becomes

if (x$A <= 5 & abs(x$B) >= 2) {
    if (x$B > 2) {
        x$Y <- "YES"
    } else {
        x$Y <- "NO"
    }
} else {
    x$Y <- NA
}
```

The second nested `ifelse()` corresponds to the inner `if` above.  It checks the value of `x$B` to see if it be greater than 2, or less than -2 (one of these much be the case based on the earlier check `abs(x$B) >= 2`.  If the former be the case, then `x$Y` gets assigned to `YES`, otherwise it gets assigned to `NO`.